# Create array of objects based on another array?

Tags: javascript

I want to take an array like this:

```
var food = [
    {
        name: 'strawberry',
        type: 'fruit',
        color: 'red',
        id: 3483
    },
    {
        name: 'apple',
        type: 'fruit',
        color: 'red',
        id: 3418
    },
    {
        name: 'banana',
        type: 'fruit',
        color: 'yellow',
        id: 3458
    },
    {
        name: 'brocolli',
        type: 'vegetable',
        color: 'green',
        id: 1458
    },
    {
        name: 'steak',
        type: 'meat',
        color: 'brown',
        id: 2458
    },
]
```

And I want to create something like this dynamically:

```
var foodCategories = [
    {
        name: 'fruit',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'apple',
                type: 'fruit',
                color: 'red',
                id: 3418
            },
            {
                name: 'banana',
                type: 'fruit',
                color: 'yellow',
                id: 3458
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'vegetable',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'brocolli',
                type: 'vegetable',
                color: 'green',
                id: 1458
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'meat',
        items: [
            {
                name: 'steak',
                type: 'meat',
                color: 'brown',
                id: 2458
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Wow... yes I know that. 'How'.

Comment: Ok.. this isn't that hard... I can tell you didn't bother to read the question. Look at the 2 datasets... does it look like a direct mapping to you? That isn't just some random simple loop... I'm taking an array of objects, and based on one of their properties, am creating an object to put them all in (with the addition of a name key/pair). If you bothered looking, I gave all the information, and If you look at the answer given below, I don't think that's an entirely straightforward answer that deserves the "try it yourself" rigamarole.

Comment: If you use StackOverflow like it's meant and answer my question, then you wouldn't have to assume what I'm stuck on... the beauty of asking an INTENDED broad question instead of asking something specific like my more recent questions and getting an answer that doesn't quite address the problem.

Comment: I had to delete my comments, since whoever moderates this site did some very strange selective editing, leaving a conversation that no longer made sense.

Comment: Oh by the way.... that jsfiddle you posted? The output is wrong... you might want to check that ;)

Comment: I don't understand. I'm showing output identical to that which you describe in the question. In what manner is it wrong? Only difference I see is that your doesn't show the "strawberry" object, but I assume that was a simple omission.

Comment: ...just so it's clear, the `types` variable is not the output. That's just a temp object to quickly and easily fetch each category object. The `result` variable holds the proper data structure. *(Sorry if you knew this. Just wanted to be sure it was clear.)*

Comment: Well anyway, [here's the link](http://jsfiddle.net/6TVpV/) in case you need it in the future. And [here's an update](http://jsfiddle.net/6TVpV/1/) that is identical except that it uses `.hasOwnProperty` instead of `in`, which will avoid a rare edge case that could cause it to crash. The `in` version would be fine if `Object.create(null)` was used to make the `types` object, but that would limit you to only modern browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.  You iterate through the food array and for each object you find, you look in the foodCategories array and see if you have an object for that food type.  If you don't, you add one.  Then, you add the food item to the right category object's array.

```
var foodCategories = [];

function findTypeInArray(arr, type) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].name === type) {
            return(i);
        }
    }
    return(-1);
}

for (var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
    var item = food[i];
    var index = findTypeInArray(foodCategories, item.type);
    if (index === -1) {
        foodCategories.push({name: item.type, items: []});
        index = foodCategories.length - 1;
    }
    foodCategories[index].items.push(item);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CwEE7/